# Extracting the src url from img tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: url, beautifulsoup, extract

I am trying to obtain the URL part of the img src. I would like to get the following URL extracted : https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41YEd80s6SL._SX384_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg

What is returned is the following which I believe is the encoded image?

data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEABYWGBQYFBwaFhwYHBocIiceGBwgLjg0JzAlNiwsIjYsJTAlIzIsMDouNjA+TkBJPjpnUERYLkRHelJ8ZoZaUnYBDhoYGiAiGh4eIiIeICciRTAgHlIyNDgiSRQ4Hic2Jyk4HCcuMhwpPClJFj4eFFQ6RzIjRScgHiM2JxowNFY2Ov/AABEIARwA3AMBIgACEQEDEQH....

I did not add all of it as it is over 600 lines.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; 64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Django-Professionals-Production-websites-Python/dp/1081582162/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=django+for+professionals&qid=1597167266&sr=8-1"
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content,features="lxml")
product_title = soup.select("#productTitle")[0].get_text().strip()
author = soup.select(".contributorNameID")[0].get_text().strip()

images = soup.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    print (image['src'])
```

EDIT: other img src seem to be returning with the url, just not the one i am specifically targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it like this:

```
encoded_image = base64.b64decode(image['src'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41YEd80s6SL._SX384_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg` image, you can parse the `data-a-dynamic-image` attribute:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; 64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}

url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Django-Professionals-Production-websites-Python/dp/1081582162/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=django+for+professionals&qid=1597167266&sr=8-1"
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content,features="lxml")
product_title = soup.select("#productTitle")[0].get_text().strip()
author = soup.select(".contributorNameID")[0].get_text().strip()

images = soup.find_all('img', src=lambda s: 'data:' in s)
for image in images:
    for img in json.loads(image['data-a-dynamic-image']):
        print(img)
```

Prints:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41YEd80s6SL._SX384_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41YEd80s6SL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg
```